# ArrayLists - Add together

Tags: arrays, arraylist, merge

Hi I am trying to Merge these two array lists outside of the stack class in the driver class; I am not too sure on how to go about it. I know of the addall method if it were in the same class. Here is how I have tried.

```
package javaapplication1;
public class JavaApplication1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack stack = new Stack();
    stack.push(new Person("jeffery", "1866"));
    stack.push(new Person("rachel", "1221"));
    stack.push(new Person("amy", "2390"));
    stack.push(new Person("tom", "1943"));
    stack.push(new Person("jimbo", "11199"));
    stack.push(new Person("anna", "1250"));
    stack.push(new Person("tammy", "1800"));
    stack.push(new Person("john", "1120"));
    stack.PrintAndEmpty();

    Stack stack2 = new Stack();
    stack2.push(new Person("jillian", "1866"));
    stack2.push(new Person("jentry", "1221"));
    stack2.push(new Person("america", "2390"));
    stack2.push(new Person("timmy", "1943"));
    stack2.push(new Person("bacon", "11199"));
    stack2.push(new Person("laura", "1250"));
    stack2.push(new Person("angus", "1800"));
    stack2.push(new Person("jimmy", "1120"));
    stack2.PrintAndEmpty();

    Stack stack3 = new Stack();
    stack3.push(new Person(stack , stack2));
    System.out.println(stack, stack2);

    }


}

package javaapplication1;

import java.util.*;

public class Stack<E> {

private ArrayList<E> head;

public Stack() {
    head = new ArrayList<E>();
}

public Stack(int initialCapacity) {
//constructor... creates intitial stack
    head = new ArrayList<E>(initialCapacity);
}

public void push(E x) {
    head.add(x);
}

public E pop() {
    if (empty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return head.remove(head.size() - 1);
}

public boolean empty() {
    return head.isEmpty();
}

public int size() {
    return head.size();
}

public E peek() {
    if (empty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return head.get(head.size());
}

public void PrintAndEmpty() {
    while (!this.empty()) {
        System.out.println(pop().toString());
    }
    System.out.println("");

}
}

 package javaapplication1;


public class Person {

private String name;
private String identification;

public Person() {
    name = "";
    identification = "";
}

public Person(String n, String idNum) {
    name = n;
    identification = idNum;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getID() {
    return identification;
}

public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
}

public void setID(String idNum) {
    identification = idNum;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) // name and id are the same
            {
    return ((((Person) o).name).equals(name)
            && (((Person) o).identification).equals(identification));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Person{ + name  + identification   + '}';
    }
}
```

This is what I have just tried and it seems to not be working either

```
public static ArrayList merge(stack,stack2){

 Stack merged = new Stack();      
 merged.push(stack,stack2);
}
enter code here
```

Comment: You have `new Person(stack , stack2)` but I do not see `Person` constructor with `(Stack, Stack)` signature.

Comment: From what I can tell, you're trying to pass two Stack objects into the Person constructor. You have no constructor that accepts this. Also, you're invoking System.out.println(); which only accepts one parameter. a String object, but you're passing it two Stack objects.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to merge the two Stacks into one within your main method. A simple way to do this would be to create a new, empty stack, and iterate over all elements within your other two stacks, and push them to the third one.

Comment: so i would need a constructor in my driver class that would create a single stack from the other two that i have in there?